# Should we remove the angularjs tag from angular2 questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

The 2 projects (Angular 2 and AngularJS) are very different.

And so I think it would be useful to have all Angular 2.x questions tagged  **only** with [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) and not with [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).

This way if I filter for AngularJS, I won't get irrelevant questions about Angular2.

Comment: What about people who don't see them as being very different and want to see angular2 results when they search for angular? Also, see this related question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315481/proposal-for-handling-stale-version-specific-answers

Comment: You can filter for `[angularjs] -[angular2]` and you won't get irrelevant questions about angular2...

Comment: @EdCottrell Angular2 is **not** the new version of AngularJS, it is a **different framework**. Tagging `angularjs`+`angular2` is a non-sense.

Comment: @Mistalis I don't have any real knowledge or opinion here; I'm not claiming to be an angular* expert. Your statement, however, is contradicted by the current [description for the angular2 tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular2/info), which says it is "The second version of the AngularJS web framework." (See also [the upgrade guide on angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html), which talks about them as different versions of one framework.)

Comment: @EdCottrell Indeed, I agree that the tag description of `angular2` is confuse, it should be updated to be clearer.

Comment: But Angular2 is another project, not a new release of AngularJS. They are **very different**. I only answer on questions about AngularJS, and I ensure you that I'm absolutely unable to answer about Angular2

Comment: @Mistalis Fair enough. Also relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336015/angularjs-tag-is-mistakenly-suggested-for-angular-2-questions?rq=1 Please feel free to post an answer on either question if you want to weigh in in favor of either suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am an AngularJS answerer only, and I know how annoying it is to see Angular2 questions tagged as [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).

I have already posted [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339938/what-can-be-done-to-prevent-wrong-use-of-angularjs-tag) dealing with it. As [*@EdCottrell*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315474/4927984) pointed out in comments, it seems that [**AngularJS is a suggested tag for Angular2**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336015/angularjs-tag-is-mistakenly-suggested-for-angular-2-questions?rq=1).

### What can be done?

1. Stop suggesting [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) when [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) is tagged.
2. Even better, warn the OP when he tries to tag [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)+[angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) that he probably wants to ask only about Angular2.
3. Remove [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) from [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) questions manually when you can. I spend a lot of time doing this. It's pretty boring, but at the moment it is the best thing we can do.

However, I'm not sure that removing [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) from **all** questions tagged [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) is a great idea. It may exist questions dealing with both (for now, I have not found any).

---

*Also related: [What to do about Angular2?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2)*

Comment: Thank  you for your answer. When I asked this question, it seemed like it was bothering no one. But it would be great if the tags are finally getting cleaned.

Comment: I've been cleaning tags up and there were a number of questions from 2016 where people were asking about migration from 1.x to 2.x and they deserved to have both tags IMO.