# Proposal for handling stale / version specific answers

Tags: feature-request

As mentioned in the post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315446/code-stolen-by-highly-upvoted-outdated-answer?cb=1) there is not yet a clear procedure for helping bring stale questions and answers up to date as technology changes.

**Proposal**

A review queue for Q&A that has been active for a long time and has sufficient traffic to the page.

**Rules**

- A post must have at least 10 visits per day
- Question must have a positive vote
- Question must be at least 2 years old
- Review queue will only choose answers that are in tags which you have provided at least 20 positively voted answers. *(A new feature for the review queue if I'm not mistaken)*
- Minimum rep for access to review queue: 500 - 1000 *up for debate*

**Review Options / Process**

- User will be presented with the question and all answers/comments visible
- Review button options:

  - "Answers are version specific" *perhaps enter edit mode to tag with version specific tag*
  - "Answers are up to date"
  - "Add updated answer"
  - "Skip"
- 3 "up-to-date" votes must be provided to remove from queue and mark post in system as up-to-date, will be seen again in 2 years.
- 3 "version-specific" votes must be provided to mark the post as [version-specific]
- "Add updated answer" will not remove from queue, but instead will continue in the process where it *should* receive 3 "up-to-date" votes and then be removed from queue.
- "Skip" does the obvious and keeps it in the queue until cleared.

**Scenarios**

- A user is presented with a Q&A that is specific to `some-language < v1.5` the user would select the "Answers are version specific" and retag the post from `some-language` to `some-language-1.5` *perhaps the question title could be updated with [version-specific] or something to note that this is only for older versions of said language*
- A user is presented with a Q&A that still applies today. The user would select "Answers are up to date". The system tracks this and the post will be revisited in 2 years. *unless the other criteria is not met*
- A user is presented with a Q&A that they do not wish to spend the time to improve or do not know a way to improve the post. The user will click "skip" and the post will be forwarded along.
- A user is presented with a Q&A and would like to improve the post. The user will click "Add updated answer" and proceed to provide an updated answer. Once complete the next post in the queue will appear and the post will continue until 3 "up-to-date" votes are received.
- A user is presented with a Q&A that would be best updated with an edit to an existing answer or community wiki. The user will edit the answer (within the bounds of the existing rep rules on editing) and then save the edit. The user will then either be presented with the next post and the post will continue until 3 "up-to-date" votes are received.

Comment: I still use `some-language < v1.5`, are the answers out dated for me?

Comment: @Andy Agreed, outdated is a harsh term. Perhaps not using outdated, but `version specific`. Updated language in post. To give an example there are many developers using `vb6` in the daily jobs, and these are no less relevant questions and answers then `vb.net` in today's most current version. I am not recommending removal of any questions or answers, simply to give them new life as best practices change over time (new features, etc.)

Comment: A language like `javascript` is constantly evolving and since the runtime is node or the browsers, they stay up to date with the latest features. Backwards compatibility is mostly supported and so while the answers are not *outdated* by any means, they could be improved for new users coming in to these languages for the first time and would like to learn the modern version of the language out of the gate.

Comment: @CodeCaster Agreed, and I just want to point out to everyone **All versions of every language are still valid and important**. However, using your example, users of `ASP.Net MVC 5` finding a question with an answer using pre-v5 syntax will possibly be led down the wrong path, or be frustrated.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this idea for a number of reasons.  First being that this sounds like a lot of work to implement along with a lot of work for users that are moderating this.  That in and of itself doesn't make it bad, but it becomes really hard to justify when you haven't shown how much of a problem this really is.  (I realize there are old answers that need updating, but how many are there?) If we were to flip the switch on this today, how many questions would instantly drop into this queue? 1,000? 10,000? 5?  Second, what does this solve that can't be done with a comment or the edit button?

Comment: @Becuzz this isn't quite the first question about outdated answers. It _is_ a real problem, and it's becoming almost impossible to find the proper, current answer to a lot of common problems in the tags I'm active in. It's starting to become even a bigger problem than duplicate questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not saying it isn't a problem.  I'd just like to know how bad of a problem it is and if this is an appropriate solution or if it is overkill.

Comment: @CodeCaster There's nothing "agressive" about the downvoting here. People do not agree with the proposal. It's as simple as that. There have been other proposals that I thought were better. (I've upvoted [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272651/1906307), for instance.)

Comment: @Becuzz I accept your challenge to investigate the amount of questions that fit this criteria and will report back with findings. Also I agree that this seems to be an entirely different type of review queue that would obviously take time to develop and implement. For your second question, the intent here is to take an active stance on keeping the content of the Q&A here up to date by presenting **willing** reviewers the chance to sift through posts in a single place without having to deep dive into tags and go searching through lists. That is a passive stance and I am proposing an active one.

Comment: @Becuzz from the limited information we have access to (can't see views on date) there appear to be [2,261](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/427989) javascript posts that match this criteria, and [34,175](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/427995/545246/) in all tags. (Again with my best guess with the information available)

Comment: @Louis This is a community and votes of any kind are welcomed. Just shows a chance to improve the proposal. The proposal you linked does look good but fails to address 2 points. Questions specifically for an older version of a language or framework should not be deemed as "invalid" by marking them as obsolete. They are still relevant **for that version of the language**. And second, the process is still *passive* meaning that users have to go out in search of these, or encounter them in the wild. I believe that this should be an *active* process, bringing the questions to willing users' attn.

Comment: @SnareChops Interesting.  I took your query and modified it a bit.  When I looked for only questions with at least one answer, and that weren't closed or deleted, the number of total questions dropped to 26930.  If I further cut it down to ones with an accepted answer (which I feel is more likely to cause confusion when the "solved" marker is there), it drops down to [19,232](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/428028/potentially-outdated-posts).  (cont)

Comment: @SnareChops (cont) However, you used the last activity date to try to limit the data.  That, I believe is just the last time the post got bumped because there was a new answer or edit activity.  That means it really isn't a good indicator of when the last view was, but is at least a decent guess.  If I remove that filter, the number jumps up to over [2.3 million](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/428031/potentially-outdated-posts-no-activity-date).  (cont)

Comment: @SnareChops (cont) I assume that the views criteria would cut that down, but now I wonder how we could possibly handle that with a queue (no matter which number you look at).  I mean, we have a hard enough time with the CV queue and that usually hovers somewhere around 8-9k.  I can't imagine we have enough people to handle this new queue.

Comment: @Becuzz I suspect that this number would drop very quickly once initially filtered through

Comment: @SnareChops Agreed.  Even if we take your number of 34,175 questions and just for the sake or argument, say that the proposed filters drop it down to 10% of that (3,417).  That's still a decent queue.  Add to it the restrictions on who can review a given question, we have potentially less reviewers (would be interesting to see the ratio of questions to potential reviewers in a given tag, picking some popular ones and some not so popular ones).  So I'm still not sure we could keep up.

Comment: That's a very good point especially for very obscure tags. However I do also feel that the number of these would be proportional to the number of users in the tags.

Comment: @SnareChops There's no doubt that the proposal I mentioned needs tweaking but at the end of the day, I much prefer a system that has *users* bring up cases to the attention of other users rather than a system that decides *automatically* to bring up cases for review. At any rate, my comment was made primarily as a counter to the notion that people who downvoted here just *do not care about obsolete answers*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could be proven wrong here, but I'm pretty sure this isn't going to happen, for a number of reasons.

Let's be clear about the problem that you're trying to solve. You phrased it as:

> there is not yet a clear procedure for helping bring stale questions and answers up to date as technology changes

I would phrase it as

> Users don't know what they're looking for, are unfamiliar with changes in the technology they are using, or can't be bothered to look at existing information in a post (including existing version-specific tags, existing version information in the title or the post body, or the date).

**I'm not sure this is a problem that SO can solve beyond the existing system of adding answers, commenting, and, most importantly, voting.** I'm even less sure that your proposal would do much to help.

First, you're proposing an enormous amount of work—an entirely new and unusually time-consuming review queue—to solve a very basic problem.

Second, you assume that users who stumble across outdated information don't post new answers, vote accordingly, leave comments, or otherwise make improvements right now. Or at least, you assume that that doesn't happen often enough. I don't think it's clear that this is really a problem. If a post draws that many views per day and is really outdated, *why isn't it already getting new answers, new comments, or other feedback?*

Third, I'm not really sure the problem exists. I tried to filter Main for questions meeting your criteria (`Question age >= 2 years`, `daily views >= 10`, positive question score) using the very crude search [`views:7300.. created:..2014-01 score:1..`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=views%3a7300..%20created%3a..2014-01%20score%3a1..). This over-counts a good bit, because a post from, say, 2012, would actually need > 14000 votes to meet your criteria. Anyway, I got 345,959 results. Sorting by age and looking at the first ten results, I only see a few that are at all version-specific. For example:

- [Installing Bower on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21491996/2057919) Says "I'm trying to install Bower on XUbuntu 13.10" in the first line of the question, and the top/accepted answer offers both current and legacy solutions.
- [Accordion using AngularJS and CSS animations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21491156/2057919) Tagged css3. The question lacks a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the top/accepted answer is really only a link-only answer, anyway.
- [Change bootstrap popover background color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21490989/2057919) This actually looks like a decent candidate for some updating because Bootstrap continues to evolve and there is no version-specific information currently in the question. But on the other hand, the question and top answer really have little to do with Bootstrap in the first place and are more about proper use of CSS selectors.
- [How to add angularjs ui bootstrap tooltips dynamically to existing markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21490194/2057919) Hey! Finally, a real candidate for some tweaking... maybe. I don't know enough angular.js to say for sure.

So, in 10 questions, I found one that might legitimately benefit from this kind of updating, and I don't even know for sure.

Fourth, and possibly most importantly: what's the point? What do we do with answers that are outdated, but for which no one has a great solution using the latest and greatest version of the FooBar language or XYZ library or whatever it is? What happens when the post is incorrectly marked up-to-date by people who are robo-reviewing? What about when it's up to date on February 1 and FooBar version 2.9 drops on February 7, rendering the answer obsolete? It's a never-ending cycle. I suspect that the cycle will mostly be never-ending [turd polishing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308139/2057919). We'll just bump lots of really old questions to the top of the home page, over and over, in an effort to curate stuff that—by the premise of your question—is largely obsolete anyway.

So, my guess: not happening. My preference: not happening.

Comment: Well phrased and some excellent points in there. You're second point is the most interesting. The "issue" of dealing with stale posts appears to be that we are in need of better "training" of upcoming users. Something to explain to them what to do when they come across an old post that could use a little freshening up with the answers. I do agree and not contest that there are *a lot* of users that **are** updating old answers with updated answers and bringing these into the current times.  And perhaps the "problem" really only exists in a small part of the posts that fit the proposed criteria

Comment: I will therefor rescind my current proposal and take some time to think of improvements to this. A way to handle this more lightly and without a review queue, but also help to improve the quality of the posts on this site.

Comment: @SnareChops Yeah, I have no doubt there are both (1) some stale answers that need to be updated or at least commented upon and (2) some stale answers that are already getting that attention organically. The real question is whether there's a good way to fix the first group that doesn't also require us to fix the "users don't read instructions" problem. If we fix *that* problem, the need for SO itself goes way down. :)

Comment: Good point. If they did that, we'd all be out of jobs :)

Comment: As someone trying to learn Angular2, I can say StackOverflow has been an anti-resource.   Questions and answers are specific to alpha, beta, and RC releases and are simply no longer relevant and/or no longer work.  None of the answers specify what version the hack/solution was created on.  My new rule of thumb:  if it was answered before 2016-09-14, keep looking.