# angularjs tag is mistakenly suggested for Angular 2 questions

Tags: discussion, bug, tags

From my own observations, only 20% of questions that have [both `[angularjs]` and `[angular2]` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs+angular2) really address both frameworks at the same time or even mention them both.

It isn't a coincidence. `[angularjs]` is suggested every time when Angular 2 question is created (probably triggered by `angular` keyword or the terms that are common for both frameworks).

I suppose that `[angularjs]` is chosen deliberately by the users because it is listed in suggested tags in newly created Angular 2 questions. I'm not sure if `[angularjs]` tag is chosen by the users because they consider SO suggestions impeccable or just think that it may be a good idea to add an extra tag since it was suggested anyway. But the result is tag noise.

The point here is that AngularJS (Angular 1) and Angular 2 are *different frameworks*, and `[angularjs]` shouldn't be suggested in questions that mention `Angular 2` or `Angular2` and do not mention `AngularJS` or `Angular 1` at the same time.

I fix the issue for the questions I'm involved in, but there are already 2600+ possibly mistagged questions (and counting).

Can the suggestion engine be fixed somehow?

Comment: How about the angular community bite the bullet and have a single tag for both, and guide yourself from cues within the question to narrow it down... otherwise you will see this problem for a long, long time.

Comment: @Braiam:  **No.**  That's a terrible idea.  Angular 1 and Angular 2 are *worlds* removed from one another, in both code structure and recommended approaches.  To put it another way, that'd be the equivalent of using one tag to describe both C and C++.

Comment: @Makoto who cares that they are different, the same people are answering both anyways...

Comment: @Braiam: By that logic, you could just merge the HTML and JavaScript tags, as the same people are answering both anyways.

Comment: A very logical bug.

Comment: @Braiam this is just not true.

Comment: Shouldn't we do something similar as Python? Have one common [angular] tag and a [angularjs-1.x] tag perhaps next to [angular2]? No idea if the common tag is really necessary, but I guess that when a next version comes (eg. angular 3), the common tag can become more useful than it is right now because v1 and v2 are quite different.

Comment: @Knu where is your data to disprove me? At least 4 out 20 highest scored answerer are the same users.  So simply saying "this is not true" is incredibly unconstructive and irrelevant

Comment: @Braiam you are confusing intersection with inclusion.

Comment: @Braiam is at least 4 out of 20 a reference? I think that's a pretty low number of users in both groups. 11/20 users in jQuery match JavaScript, I don't think that's a reference either. Sure, JavaScript is an umbrella for tags including jQuery, but that's exactly what's happening here as well, since AngularJS is (mistakenly) being used as an umbrella as well, but also as a tag to describe AngularJS 1.x.

Comment: @Braiam Currently it is not necessary to know Angular 1 to succeed in Angular 2. A2 was just released, and existing A2 experts are early adopters with A1 background. The things will change very soon, the problem will persist.

Comment: I agree this is annoying, but hardly a bug. The software is doing exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I tend to just remove the angularjs tag from angular2 questions.l when I come across them