# Now can we burninate the Angular4 tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

`Angular2` was discussed at length [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2), however I feel the discussion has moved on.

When Angular2 was released, it was known as Angular2, so it made sense to have a tag reflecting that.

As we know, [this post](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html) then decreed 'Its just `Angular`', but for historic reasons the Angular2 tag still seemed valid, as that's what we'd spent years calling it.

I upgraded to Angular v4.0 yesterday. Unlike the massive upheaval going between Angular 1 and Angular 2, it really was simple. In fact, **No code changes** were required for the upgrade.

With this in mind, it makes sense to treat it in a similar way to the 'reactjs' tag (now at version 15+) and go with the 'It's just Angular' philosophy.

The angular 'major version' upgrade will happen every 6 months. Surely we don't want to litter our beloved community with Angular5, Angular6...Angular20? It will make searching for answers much more confusing when the framework is *fundamentally the same*.

So far, only [79 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular4) have this tag.

Shouldn't we make the decision now to avoid the future mess?

**Edit**

I looked up the criteria for burnination. [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/852806) shows the criteria for burning tags. In particular, I believe the `Angular4` tag fails the "When a tag can be replaced with a combination of more generic tags" criteria.

Comment: I don't think it's useful to have another discussion about this, unless we know **who** will step up and take action. Is it up to the users to fix this? Should Moderators or CMs get involved and make a decision?

Comment: @Stijn - I agree the *who* is important and I don't know the answer to that. I assume the people with the power will be involved on Meta and the creation of the Angular4 tag takes us in the wrong direction imo.

Comment: BURNINATE!.. BURNINATE!..BURNINATE!

Comment: @JeruLuke: Are you trying to summon Trogdor?

Comment: My opinion would be to make `angular2` a synonym of `angular`, and make `angular` no longer a synonym of `angularjs`.

Comment: @honk LOL yes!!! It would burninate yeah!

Comment: @Stijn Normally the first place to look is the SOCVR room, but for 79 questions... that can be done by a single person in 15 minutes.

Comment: A reasonable short-term alternative would be for someone to unlink/unsynonymify the "angular" tag from "angularjs", and let people start using it, and also for people to start retagging posts using "angular2" when they get the chance.

Comment: @TylerH the problem isn't retagging these 79 questions, it's solving the current mess of the other angular tags first (linked in the first paragraph).

Comment: @TylerH On second thought, I suppose we could retag all these to [tag:angular2] to start with, even though that tag is still subject to change.

Comment: What about [tag:angular3], with 2 questions (one of which uses [tag:angular2], [tag:angular3], _and_ [tag:angular4] at the same time)?

Comment: @torazaburo We also need to solve the problem of people tagging Angular2+ questions with [tag:angularjs].

Comment: The new angular libraries use names: `@angular/core`, `@angular/http`, etc. to distinguish from `angular`, `angular-ngroute`, etc. Could that convention be used here?

Comment: Can I suggest that we "Break out the Angular4 Grinder"?

Comment: Maybe tags with libraries that have semver should use semver themselves.

Comment: We have the same problem with `Swift`. We got `swift`, `swift2`, `swift2.2`, `swift3`. I guess we will get `swift4` soon...

Comment: @JamesHughes I'm lost. What's the reference?

Comment: @braiam, was the best I could come up with. You use an angle grinder to destroy things?

Comment: @JamesHughes I know what's an angle and a grinder, that should give you a idea.

Comment: http://s7g3.scene7.com/is/image//ae235?src=ae235/5726P_P&$prodImageMedium$

Answer (score 22):

Does it make sense to use Angular for everything 2+ and create an Angular1 tag for those questions? I mean it's basically a separate library.

Comment: From my understanding, it is `Angular` for everything 2+ and `AngularJS` for the initial version.

Comment: @MattRowland while that works that seems unintuitive.

Comment: It would only be unintuitive during the transition. After that, it would align with the industry and be more intuitive than another solution.

Comment: Or, you know, a single tag. 'It's just Angular'

Comment: I don't recommend a single tag for Angular.  AngularJS is a very different thing than Angular 2 and up.  I like @MattRowland's suggestion.

Comment: And there is new Angular1 code being written and there is code that will never be migrated to Angular 2+ in enterprises so Angular1 may have a lifespan similar to Python 2

Comment: Perhaps Angular and AngularJS would work for those that are pretty "in" Angular at this point, but I think you'd get a lot of people just starting that would tag an Angular question as AngularJS. I'd probably be guilty of doing that. I do like the Angular1 and Angular ones, that'd make sense to me who is somewhat rusty to the nomenclature.

Comment: @ArtB *“while that works that seems unintuitive”* – It’s not just unintuitive for SO tags. It’s unintuitive everywhere. Googling for Angular (any of the two types) is very complicated at the moment; kind of googling for Go… I blame the Angular team/Google for that… >_> – Anyway, using `Angular` and `AngularJS` would be confusing but it would be the *right* thing.

Comment: @ArtB Maybe we should have both [tag:AngularJS] and [tag:Angular1] and set one up as a synonym of the other? Although… It appears nobody has tried creating any [tag:Angular1] questions yet, so I wonder if an [tag:angular1] tag would be really necessary.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Though why not burninate angularjs afterwards?

Comment: A1 and A2 are apples and oranges, and Angular team had referred to AngularJS as 'Angular' semi-officially for quite long time before to create confusion. Having `angular` and `angularjs`/`angular1` separate tags surely won't add clarity, there's already existing problem [with mistagged Angular questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336015/angularjs-tag-is-mistakenly-suggested-for-angular-2-questions), and it worsen. Probably `angular2+` would make more sense.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone who cares, "from the horse's mouth": http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2017/01/branding-guidelines-for-angular-and.html

> We agree with this and we have accepted the suggestions many of you have brought up to return to our roots with the name AngularJS for any 1.x release, and Angular for any 2+ release. Our goal is to bring as much consistency as possible especially going forward, while reducing the maintenance burden caused by past branding inconsistencies.

Answer (score 7):

My fear with this move by the Angular team is that "What happens when we're on Angular v20, and I go to fix an issue on a legacy project that's built in Angular v12? There was this little idiosyncrasy that they remedied in v15 but I can't remember the workaround for it before then."

Also, with major version releases, they can change whatever they want at any point. Say some breaking change gets introduced in v8 that makes all the answers before then irrelevant?

I don't like littering the site with several version tags, especially with the speed that they're proposing they will release them in. However, I really see it as a necessary evil to make sure those idiosyncrasies are easy to find.

Comment: "necessary evil to make sure those idiosyncrasies are easy to find." you mean cargo cult... why do we need them? AFAIK, that kind of information is easily included in the body of the question itself if necessary, and the problems arising between versions can be perfectly asked without including the version information.

Comment: React is in the same situation and I'm yet to find a case of this happening (that remained unsolved).

Comment: @Braiam That's fine if you're asking a question, but what about when you're searching for an answer?

Comment: @krillgar "angular my problem"

Comment: Basically we should treat Angular like every other versioned thing on here: Have a main tag `Angular` for everything Angular 2 and up. And then introduce version tags `Angular-2.x`, `Angular-4.x`, `Angular-5.x`, … that are only added for *very version-specific* things in addition to the main tag.

Comment: Seems like the little version number bugs/idiosyncrasies that come and go for libs like jQuery are mentioned in the Q (or the A).  It's worked out well, I think.

Comment: @poke no. We should treat angular as angular and stop being cry babies trying to misrepresent stuff. People will google angular, just give them angular.

Comment: @Braiam Not sure what you are referring to with “misrepresent stuff”. And who cares what people *google*, we don’t follow what any random visitor thinks is correct. That’s why we have proper tags and why we edit questions instead of just accepting them in the way they are created.

Comment: @poke yet you don't even know which is the main consumer of tags: answerers, and those guys are the people that are less concerned with versions, rather than topics.

Comment: @Braiam As someone who answers a lot, I can say that there are a lot of situations where the specific version is very important…

Comment: @poke and why that information should be included on the tags? BTW, [with the exception of python-3.x, the bulk of your answers are on questions without versioned tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke?tab=tags).