# What can be done to prevent wrong use of AngularJS tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since the release of Angular2, I see a lot of questions on StackOverflow tagged as **`angular2`** + **`angularjs`**.

As a reminder, AngularJS is the first version of Angular, and the tag **should not** be use for Angular2 question. This info appears at the end of the [**`angularjs`** tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info):

> AngularJS (a.k.a. AngularJS 1) is an open-source JavaScript framework.
>   Its goal is to augment browser-based applications with
>   Model–View–Whatever (MV*) capability and reduce the amount of
>   JavaScript needed to make web applications functional. These types of
>   applications are also frequently known as single-page applications
>   (SPAs). **The next version 2.0 has its own tag, see [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2)**.

As other AngularJS answerers, I spend much time to edit questions about Angular2 carrying both tags (**`angular2`** and **`angularjs`**).

---

I always remove the **`angularjs`** one, but what can be done, as an improvement in the future, to avoid the use of both tags?

- Can we warn users that there questions are probably **only about Angular2** if they use both tags?
- Should we write in the top of **`angularjs`** description something about it (like for [this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsfiddle/info))?

Comment: There is a similar problem with `ionic-framework` and `ionic2` as well

Comment: Between `flex`, `flexbox`, and `flex-lexer`, too