# Duplicate AngularJS tags: [angularjs-ng-repeat], [ng-repeat]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are 2 tags that exists for questions about Angular's ng-repeat:

- [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat): 10 followers, 2.1k questions
- [angularjs-ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat): 577 followers, 6k questions

[angularjs-ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat) is more popular, better described. Those tags are exactly about the same Angular directive.

I would suggest to delete replace all [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat) by [angularjs-ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat) and then delete [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat).

Comment: Are all of the questions tagged [tag:ng-repeat] about the AngularJS thingadongdong? If so, then merging the tags and creating a synonym is appropriate. If not, we'll need to hold off until someone can clean up the [tag:ng-repeat] tag. (Wait. I took your word for it that [tag:angularjs-ng-repeat] is "more popular", but looking at the numbers you also provided, the exact opposite appears to be true!)

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296857/burninate-73-angularjs-directive-tags?rq=1).

Comment: @CodyGray: Oops, I had reversed the numbers. Fixed!

Comment: Is there an ng-repeat analog in Angular (i.e., Angular 2+)? Because there are a bunch of repetitions amongst the angular tags now ([tag:angular2-template], [tag:angular2-services], etc.) Luckily, there's no `angular2-ng-repeat` tag, but having `angularjs-ng-repeat` means you'll have questions with [`angular2` `angularjs-ng-repeat`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2+angularjs-ng-repeat), which looks a bit odd.

Comment: @Mike Interesting point. But this issue concerns the whole Angular tags, including `angularjs` one. See [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339938/what-can-be-done-to-prevent-wrong-use-of-angularjs-tag).

Comment: Well, I guess my point is, why even do anything with these tags until we've figured out what to do with Angular/AngularJS tags in general? What if the decision is to just use `angularjs` (or `angular-legacy`) + `ng-repeat` for that combination, and `angular` + `ng-repeat` for those referencing Angular 2+?

Comment: Can't we just get rid of all the `ng-*` and `angular-ng-*` tags? They seem useless.